# How to pass parameters to a modal using thymeleaf?

Tags: html, grails, thymeleaf

I just starting in a project where we're using thymeleaf and I'm new to the technology.
It's a simple modal to confirm an object to be deleted. So they want me to add the name of the item we're deleting on the message instead of a generic message like: "Are you sure you want to delete?"
They want: "Are you you want to delete Item_Name?"
So I need to pass this name as parameter.

That's the code I have the display the modal:

```
<button id="btnDelete" value="delete" type="button" class="btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-object-id="12345" data-object-name="NNN" th:attr="data-object-id=''+${assignment.assignmentId}+'', data-object-name='/nonInstructionalWorkload/deleteAssignment?asssignmentId='+${assignment.assignmentId}+'', data-target='#deleteAssignmentModal'">
```

And that's the code I have on the modal html:

```
<form role="form" th:action="@{/deleteAssignment}"
      name="assignmentDeleteForm" id="assignmentDeleteForm" method="post">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteWorkItemabel">Confirm Assignment Delete</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Assignment will be deleted, are you sure you want to proceed?</p>
            <input type="hidden" id="deleteId" name="deleteId" value="nnnn"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="btnDelConfirm" class="btn btn-primary">
            Yes
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="btnDelCancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            No
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

At this point is where I need to add more information on the confirmation message about the assignment item being deleted.

Already tried some approached to get the parameters but didn't work so I'm looking for more option.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using Thymeleaf instead of GSPs in a Grails project?

Answer (score 3):

Thymeleaf is just template engine that takes your templeate and generate static html out of it. So passing dynamic values to your modal is a javascript work (unless you generate separate modal for each item, but this would be silly).

Using thymeleaf you have to generate a `data-` attribute containing desired item's name inside the button which opens modal, and that's all. You've already did such thing within `th:attr`:

```
th:attr="data-object-id=''+${assignment.assignmentId}+'', data-object-name='/nonInstructionalWorkload/deleteAssignment?asssignmentId='+${assignment.assignmentId}+'', data-target='#deleteAssignmentModal'"
```

The code above will generate attributes `data-object-id`,`data-object-name` and `data-target` inside the button. I assume that `data-object-name` is the one you want to use (however it looks more like an URL).

Now you can customize your modal's content using javascript. I can see, that you are using **bootstrap** as your frontend library, so you should take a look at [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target), to have an idea how to accomplish that.

Javascript code below should work fine for you:

```
$('#deleteAssignmentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var objectName = button.data('object-name') // Extract info from data-object-name attribute

  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body p').text('Do you want to delete ' + objectName + '?')
})
```

Comment: thank you but l am having issue with the jquery code. There is no place l put that it gets called. what am l doing wrong?

Comment: @leeCoder Hard to say without seeing the code. My guess is you didn't include a javascript of the modal plugin or its dependencies. Have you included `bootstrap.js` to your page?

Answer (score 0):

The sample project on GitHub you can clone and test it. Full video under the readme.

https://github.com/ibrahimkarayel/todoBoot/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/home.html

```
<div class="modal modal-delete" th:id="modal-delete+${task.id }">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">×
                </button>
                <h3 id="delModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="error-text"><strong>Are you sure you want to
                    delete this task ?</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn " data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <a th:href="@{/task/delete/{id}(id=${task.id})}">
                    <span class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">Delete</span></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!--end delete modal-->

<script>
    $('#modal-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
        $('#modal-deleteHiddenId').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href'));
    });
</script>
```